# Word for conceding a debate just because the opponent wants it that way

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In an argument, is there a single term or fallacy for a scenario where someone concedes a debate just for the sake that the opponent wants it conceded that way

For eg: *Yes, I agree to what you say because you always want your point to be accepted as true*

Comment: It is for conceding a debate. Edited the body

Comment: There's [a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592386) asked two days ago.

Comment: I think there is a slight difference as highlighted by my example, so undeleted my question

Answer (score 1):

OK I agree - **anything for a quiet life**

> [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/anything-for-a-quiet-life)
> used for saying that you will let someone do what they want in order to avoid an argument

Answer (score -1):

The closest term I can think of is "Acquiescence". Perhaps a "placatory concession" would also fit.

Comment: Some references which back up the information you give would help...